# C# Reflection Emit Func with new instance

Tags: c#, reflection, func, reflection.emit

I'am trying to emit the following code via Reflection:

```
 this.Inputs = new DynamicCollection<IFunctionInput<Digital>>((string name) => new FunctionInput<Digital>(this, name));
```

The ctor of the DynamicCollection takes a func and looks like:

```
public DynamicCollection ( Func<string, T> createPin )
```

But when i look at the compiled IL code it gives me:

```
IL_0008: ldarg.0
    IL_0009: ldarg.0
    IL_000a: ldftn instance class [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.IFunctionInput`1<valuetype [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.Digital> CM.Server.LogicalAndFunctionServer::'<.ctor>b__0_0'(string)
    IL_0010: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<string, class [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.IFunctionInput`1<valuetype [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.Digital>>::.ctor(object,  native int)
    IL_0015: newobj instance void class CM.Server.DynamicCollection`1<class [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.IFunctionInput`1<valuetype [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.Digital>>::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<string, !0>)
    IL_001a: stfld class [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.IDynamicCollection`1<class [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.IFunctionInput`1<valuetype [CM.Shared]CM.Shared.Digital>> CM.Server.LogicalAndFunctionServer::'<Inputs>k__BackingField'
    IL_001f: ldarg.0
```

But where in this IL can i find the instanciation of the FunctionInput-class.
I can only see some IFunctionInput-types which is the interface implemented by FunctionInput but how does this code know the real type to instanciate?
Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've solved it by myself. Haven't thought about that the lambda is capturing "this", so it creates a closure-class for it.
Telerik's "Just Decompile" doesnt show Closure-classes but i've seen it in ildasm.